# facebook php access token

Tags: php, facebook

I have all of the files (facebook.php, base_facebook.php, index.php) in the same directory. My server(s) are Apache, and both support php. 
My code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
try
{
echo("STARTING<br>");
require("facebook.php");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo("ERROR1: $e");
}

try
{
$facebook = new Facebook("***","###");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo("ERROR2: $e");
}
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo("Access token: ".$token."<br>");
```

My text output is as follows:

```
STARTING
ERROR1: Object id #1before create fb instance

Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in /(FILE PATH)/index.php on line 16

Note: line 16 is: $facebook = new Facebook("***","###");
```

The first catch statement is printing: Object Id #1. Then it does my next print statement. Then it returns Fatal Error that is not caught. What am I missing here?

Why can the server not get the correct access token?

Comment: Your require if failing. I generally wouldn't wrap a try/catch around the require. You want the script to fail if the required file isn't found. Unless you're going to try and gracefully handle that. It's not a very likely situation once you get this problem fixed.

Comment: "Class `Facebook` not found" - this is obvious message I belive:) Are you able to include any other file? `echo get_include_path()` might help

Comment: @Ruslan Polutsygan, Yes I am able to include other files. I tried the echo get_include_path(). It told me it was including the file from here: .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear

Comment: @Rilcon42: maybe filename is "Facebook.php"(with capital first letter)?

Comment: @Rilcon42: and one more thing - you can't echo exception object. What does this code say `echo('ERROR1: '.$e->getMessage()); die();`?

Comment: @Ruslan Polutsygan, Thank you for all your help, but unfortunately I am unable to test your code since the project has been canceled due to a change in strategy.

Answer (score 2):

You failed to `require` the facebook.php, hence the `ERROR1: Object id #1` - you're trying to echo out the exception error object. Try

```
catch ($e) {
   die($e->getMessage());
}
```

instead.

You should not catch that kind of error. if a require fails, the only useful solution is to abort execution, because you've not gotten what you REQUIRED to continue execution.

Basically you've implemented a PHPized version of visual basic's `on error resume next`, with all the nasty stupidity that goes with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code before the header is sent :

Go here for further information : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Basically, put this on very on top of your code :

```
<?php
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config[‘secret’] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
?>
```

Then load your HTML (In MVC style will be better for maintenance ;-)

Comment: I made the change, but it did not affect the functionality of my code.